# Center first element of React-Native list on screen without permanent border

Tags: android, css, react-native

When running React Native code on Android, I have a list of items, where each item has an image associated with it. I'm trying to make the first element of the list to be on the center of the screen.

I created this component

```
export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <List 
          Items={Items}
          align-items="right"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  }
});
```

But the problem is that the first item is not centered on the screen:

[image]

To move the image more to the center, I added this to the style:

```
{paddingLeft: "15%"}
```

Now, the image looks like this:

[image]

This looks good for the start, but as I scroll towards the right through the list, the border on the left does not disappear.

Any idea how to center the first element of the list, without having a permanent border to the left?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try making the style conditional...

```
{paddingLeft: this.state.isFirstItem && "15%"}
```

Then when you scroll to the second item, `this.setState({isFirstItem: false})`

Comment: This is `Flatlist`. How can I know that I scrolled to the second item in the list. Is there a lifecycle method that gets triggered?

Comment: Looking through the [FlatList Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), it looks like these may prove promising [onViewableItemsChanged](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onviewableitemschanged) and [recordInteraction()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#recordinteraction)